# Connect Ruby on Rails to existing MySQL database (previously installed XAMMP)

Tags: mysql, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, xampp

I have installed ruby on rails(gitlab exactly) on ubuntu machine with `xampp`, but I failed to connect existing `mysql` to ror. I can install the gem `mysql2` by running

```
"gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-include=/opt/lampp/include --with-mysql-config=/opt/lampp/bin/mysql_config".
```

But when I ran "bundle install", it came out:

```
 "Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."
```

and

```
"An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11)"
```

and so on. What should I do?

Comment: I believe XAMPP doesn't install mysql in the place it should. It creates some kind of isolated install. I had that problem. Install MySQL as a seperate entity to XAMPP and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, installing a lib for `mysql` fixed it for me. 
Try running:

```
 sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and try to install the gem again.

Hope it works!